# ngRepeat with custom index coming up blank

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a large amount of arrays in a large form in my application. In order to make splicing out specific data from my datasets based on the user's selections, I've structured my arrays like this example:

```
var userList = [];
userList[user1.id] = user1;
userList[user2.id] = user2;
```

This lets me splice out specific elements without looping through the entire collection by using:

```
userList.splice(user1.id, 1);
```

However, when I try to make a list of Users in my HTML using an ng-repeat statement, it comes up blank. My HTML is:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in userList">{{user.name}}</div>
```

I suspect that ngRepeat uses 0,1,2.. by default and doesn't know how to handle my custom indexes. I've checked several sources but I can't really make sense of things. It did work when I added my users by simply pushing them into the array instead of assigning them to a specific index, so I know the rest of my code works fine.

Help? D:

EDIT:

The addition of a trackBy "track by user.id" didn't fix it.

Plunkr! http://plnkr.co/edit/8hANBvXAIplHsq0Ph6GX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because Array's indexes are zero-based meaning, they go from 0, 1, 2, ... n and you're trying to put alphanumeric indexes if you check the below code snippet the length of the array is zero.

```js
var user1 = {
  id: 'A1B2',
  name: 'Pete'
};

var user2 = {
  id: 'A2B3',
  name: 'Jeff'
};

var userList = [];
userList[user1.id] = user1;
userList[user2.id] = user2;
console.log(userList);
console.log('length: ' + userList.length);
console.log(userList['A1B2']);
console.log(userList.A1B2); // behaving as JavaScript Object not array as property set using userList[user2.id] = user2;
```

So you need to set the data structure properly, you can set it as follows specifying the index of the array or by using the `push` function on the array to add a new item to the array.

```
  var user1 = {
    id: 'A1B2',
    name: 'Pete'
  };

  var user2 = {
    id: 'A2B3',
    name: 'Jeff'
  };

  $scope.userList = [];
  $scope.userList[0] = user1; // $scope.userList.push(user1);
  $scope.userList[1] = user2; // $scope.userList.push(user2);
```

I suggest you change the collection name from `userList` to `users` it looks clean, you don't need to suffix a collection with the List keyword I think it looks untidy, just make the name plural.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  var pete = {
    id: 'A1B2',
    name: 'Pete'
  };

  var jeff = {
    id: 'A2B3',
    name: 'Jeff'
  };

  vm.users = [];
  vm.users[0] = pete;
  vm.users[1] = jeff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">
      <span>{{user.id}}, {{user.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This wasn't what I was looking for, but it helped explain why what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

change the `id` of each individual user to `numeric` from `alpha-numeric` as pointed by Adbul, `array's` indexes are `number` based

for eg:-

```
var user1 = {
  id: 0, //Any numeric Value
  name: 'Pete'
}
```

and then try `$scope.userList[user1.id] = user1;`

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="user in userList">{{user.name}}</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I added a Plunkr if you want to take a look :)

Comment: sure drop the link

Answer (score 0):

Do following

Controller:

```
  $scope.userList = [];
  $scope.userList.push(user1);
  $scope.userList.push(user2);
```

View:

```
      <tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td></tr>
```

Comment: This simply undoes my initial idea, and does not provide a solution to my specific problem.